# Groovy - XML Tree Traversal breadthFirst() method using * as syntactic sugar

Tags: xml, groovy, xml-parsing

The [Groovy documentation](http://www.groovy-lang.org/single-page-documentation.html) in the processing XML section mentions that `breadthFirst()` is synonymous to the shorter syntax of `*`. However, the `*` usage ends up only traversing one level beneath the parent node:

```
def books = '''\
<response>
   <books>
      <book available="20" id="1">
         <title>foo</title>
         <author id="1">foo author</author>
      </book>
      <book available="14" id="2">
         <title>bar</title>
         <author id="2">bar author</author>
      </book>
   </books>
</response>'''

def response = new XmlSlurper().parseText(books)
def bk = response.'*'.find { node ->
   node.name() == 'book' && node['@id'].toInteger() == 2
}
assert bk.empty
```

whereas using `breadthFirst()` explicitly does what I expect both to do which is to do breadth-first traversal:

```
def books = '''\
<response>
   <books>
      <book available="20" id="1">
         <title>foo</title>
         <author id="1">foo author</author>
      </book>
      <book available="14" id="2">
         <title>bar</title>
         <author id="2">bar author</author>
      </book>
   </books>
</response>'''

def response = new XmlSlurper().parseText(books)
def bk = response.breadthFirst().find { node ->
   node.name() == 'book' && node['@id'].toInteger() == 2
}
assert bk.title == 'bar' // bk is no longer an empty list of children
```

`*` semantics are clearly different than `breadthFirst()`. Is this expected behavior or did I miss something in the doc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the documentation does not emphasize that `*` is actually a shorthand that only gets the *direct* children of the node at which it is invoked. The example from the docs at the time of this writing is:

```
def catcherInTheRye = response.value.books.'*'.find { node->
 /* node.@id == 2 could be expressed as node['@id'] == 2 */
    node.name() == 'book' && node.@id == '2'
}
```

Notice that they did not use `response.'*'` as you did in your own example. So `*` is not really is shorthand for `breadthFirst()` (I agree the docs should be reviewed). It just means the direct children, whereas `breadthFirst()` traverses the nodes recursively. This can be confirmed from the Javadocs of [`GPathResult.getProperty`](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/util/slurpersupport/GPathResult.html#getProperty-java.lang.String-):

> Returns the specified Property of this GPathResult.
>   Realizes the follow shortcuts:
>
> - `'..'` for `parent()`
> - `'*'` for `children()`
> - `'**'` for `depthFirst()`
> - `'@'` for attribute access

I created [this pull request](https://github.com/apache/groovy/pull/517) to fix it.